# Update the attributes of the Children(FK) Model when the Parent Model attributes changes - Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have multiple connected to FK Models, each one of them having a `state -is_active` attribute.

```
class GrandParent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # state
    is_active = models.BooleanField(choices=BOOL_TYPE_CHOICES, default=BOOL_TYPE_NO)

class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # state
    is_active = models.BooleanField(choices=BOOL_TYPE_CHOICES, default=BOOL_TYPE_NO)

class Child1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # state
    is_active = models.BooleanField(choices=BOOL_TYPE_CHOICES, default=BOOL_TYPE_NO)

class Child2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # state
    is_active = models.BooleanField(choices=BOOL_TYPE_CHOICES, default=BOOL_TYPE_NO)
```

What I need (for Django Admin)- Example:

1. When the `is_active` value becomes `False` for the `Parent`, I want the `Child1, Child2` `is_active` to become also `False` if is `True`.
2. If the `Child` try to make `is_active` `True`, but the Parent `is_active=False`, to not be allowed.

---  If `Grandparent` `is_active` becomes `False` propagate down to the `Child`

I tried to do it at the `Model` level overriding `save`, but the Admin `save` is kind of passing over, `Model` `save`. also doesn't cover 2.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):            
    if not self.is_active:
        c = Child1.objects.filter(is_active=True)
        c.update(is_active=False)
```

3. Can it be done more generic? A class that is inherited and do the checks based on the subclass name and FK existence.

Comment: Can you show your custom `save` method?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid add it, but is a naive implementation that covers only 1)

Comment: How are the models connected ? Through ForeignKey ? If so, can you show us the lines ?